# Why is there a white space at the beginning of the body/html document (on top of the navigation bar)?

Tags: html, css, document-body

check the code here:

https://landing-page.adrianojedaf.repl.co

I thought it could be the overflow-x so I disable the Scroll Bar in CSS but the white space on top of the navigation-bar is still there. When I use the Browser's inspector, it seems like the white space is part of the header, but it doesn't have any margin or other property that could be generating it so I really don't know.

Comment: <img id="header-img" src=""> thats the reason why you have white space up there on your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here put this on your code instead.I remove your unknown image tag  To resolve your problem and this should work.

```html
<header id="header">
    <nav id="nav-bar">
      <div class="content-width">
        <img src="images/carrot.png">
        <a class="logo" href="index.html">Carrot</a>
        <div class="nav-right">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#submit">Features</a>
          <a class="nav-link" href="#goVideo">Process</a>
          <a class="nav-link" href="#prices">Prices</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </header>
```